# how to get string value in java

Tags: java

```
String Qty1 = "1";
String Qty2 = "2";
String  qtyString = "", bString = "", cString = "";
for(int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
{
    qtyString = String.valueOf(("Qty" + j)); 
    System.out.println("qtyString = " + qtyString);
}
```

output:

> qtyString = Qty1;
>
> qtyString = Qty2;

I would like to get qtyString = 1, qtyString = 2; I want to print Qty1 and Qty2 value in my for loop. In C#, this code works correctly. I don't know how to get qtyString value as 1, 2 in java.

Comment: You are assigning numbers to String references, which will fail (not compile). By the way, you are violating the norm of naming instance reference variable with an initial lowercase letter (`Qty1` should be `qty1`).

Comment: Also, bstring and cstring are declared and initialized but never used

Comment: @ Casey ,bstring and cstring just testing what value is get.

Comment: trying to get Qty value .. but where you have initialize ??

Comment: @Subhalaxmi Nayak , I want to get Qty1 and Qty2 value in for loop as 1, 2.

Comment: @Basil Bourque , I already edit my question to assign string in string value . I try to change Qty1 to qty1 in my code.But result is same .It is  effect nothing.

Comment: Do you want  values of Qty1 & Qty2 values in qtyString?? In your forloop???

Comment: @ashish jaiswal, I want to get Qty1 & Qty2 values in forloop.

Comment: You are abusing the method `String.valueOf`. That method is for converting other types to a string. You seem to be thinking incorrectly that the method creates a pointer/reference to a variable whose name is that string. But that is not the purpose of that method. You seem to be headed in the direction of Reflection and Introspection (btw, recommended only for special situations). See [Tutorial on Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: First make a array for Qty[ ] = [ "1", "2" ]; then only you can get the values of qty in your forloop.

Comment: Actually, I recommend that you _don't_ read the tutorial on reflection.  At least not until you have the basics mastered better.  It might give you some bad ideas about how to solve problems that are much better solved with things like arrays, maps, and other simpler concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use array of strings for this purpose.

```
String[] Qty = {"1","2"};
for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ;j++)
{
   System.out.println("qtyString = " + Qty[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

String array is needed if you want to print a list of string:

```
String[] Qty = {"1", "2"};
String qtyString = null;
for (int j = 0; i<=1; j++) {
    qtyString = Qty[j];
    System.out.println("qtyString = " + qtyString);
}

output:
qtyString = 1
qtyString = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure what you're trying to do, and you've declared `Qty1` twice in your code.  Assuming the second one is supposed to be `Qty2`, then it looks like you're trying to use string operations to construct a variable name, and get the value of the variable that way.

**You cannot do that in Java.**  I'm not a C# expert, but I don't think you can do it in C# either (whatever you did that made you say "it works in C#" was most certainly something very different).  In both those languages and in all other *compiled* languages, the compiler has to know, at compile time, what variable you're trying to access.  You can't do it at runtime.  (Technically, in Java and C#, there are ways to do it using reflection, depending on how and where your variables are declared.  But you do not want to solve your problem that way.)

You'll need to learn about maps.  Instead of separate variables, declare a `Map<String, String>` that maps the *name* that you want to associate with a value (`Qty1`, `Qty2`) with the value (which is also a `String` in this case, but could be anything else).  See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) for more information.  Your code will look something like

```
Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("Qty1", "1");
values.put("Qty2", "2");

...

 qtyString = values.get("Qty"+j);
```

(Actually, since your variable name is based on an integer, an array or `ArrayList` would work perfectly well too.  Using maps is a more general solution that works in other cases where you want names based on something else beside sequential integers.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this for java:
    static String Qty[] = {"1", "2"} ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ;j++)
    {
        System.out.println("qtyString = " + Qty[j]);
    }
}
```

And For Android:

```
String[] Qty = {"1","2"};
for(int j = 0 ; j < 2 ;j++)
{
   System.out.println("qtyString = " + Qty[j]);
}
```

Comment: Your first code snippet will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Now it only prints one value, instead of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try this examples:

**With enhanced for-loop and inline array:**

```
for(String qty : new String[]{"1", "2"})
  System.out.printf("qtyString = %s\n", qty);
```

**With enhanced for-loop and array:**

```
String [] qtys = {"1", "2"};
for(String qty : qtys)
  System.out.printf("qtyString = %s\n", qty);
```

**Using for-loop and array:**

```
String [] qty = {"1", "2"};
for(int i = 0; qty.length > i; i ++)
  System.out.printf("qtyString = %s\n", qty[i]);
```